# charts_flutter: Show y-axis value for corresponding x-axis value flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-visualization

I am trying to display a time series chart in my flutter app. The problem is when I click on a date on the x-axis, the corresponding y-value is not displayed on the y-axis. I searched intensively in the documentation, but there is no example provided like this.  What do I need to do differently?

[image: Here is a picture of the chart:]

```dart
class MyLineChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series> seriesList;
  final bool animate;

  MyLineChart(this.seriesList, {this.animate});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.TimeSeriesChart(
      seriesList,
      animate: animate,
      dateTimeFactory: const charts.LocalDateTimeFactory(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, using `LinePointHighlighter`:

```
class MyLineChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series> seriesList;
  final bool animate;

  MyLineChart(this.seriesList, {this.animate});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.TimeSeriesChart(
      seriesList,
      animate: animate,
      dateTimeFactory: const charts.LocalDateTimeFactory(),
      behaviors: [
        LinePointHighlighter(
          drawFollowLinesAcrossChart: true,
          showHorizontalFollowLine: LinePointHighlighterFollowLineType.all,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT:
Excuse me, I misread your question.

To show the values on the y-axis I think you will have to create your own `LinePointHighlighter`, or `SymbolRenderer` to pass your LinePointHighlighter. Both require you to paint on the chart's `canvas`.

Use `SelectionModelConfig` to get the selected value you want to show. See: https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/behaviors/selection_callback_example

I haven't done this myself, but I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your answer shows only the dashed lines. I also need the values to display on the y-axis. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @Er1 hi.. I would like to try your code, do you have any example how to create ```LinePointHighlighter``` ?

Comment: @uyhaW Hopefully this will help you https://gist.github.com/cirediew/c22b2736028ef06b10b934d6c863664d

Comment: @Er1 thank you very much for your help, I will try it